# boost::regexp unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have this regular expression:

```
(?:^|\\n)[ \\t]*(-(.|\\n)*?)(?=\\n[ \\t]*-|$)
```

I want to use it with this text

```
 -h --help                 Show this screen.
 --version                 Show version.
 --prefix=<path>           Set the specified path as the prefix
                           for paths mentioned below (except ones
                           specified manually).
 -c, --config=<cfg-file>   Configuration file name
                           [default: <prefix>/etc/myprog/protocols.conf].
 --script=<asl-file>       Input script file which will be played.
                           If not specified then contents of the
                           <prefix>/etc/myprog/script.active will be taken.
```

to find out each option with its description. With `<regex>` from GCC 5.3 this expression works as expected, but if I include the `<boost/regex.hpp>` (the last version at this moment) it matches

```
 --prefix=<path>           Set the specified path as the prefix
```

but not

```
 --prefix=<path>           Set the specified path as the prefix
                           for paths mentioned below (except ones
                           specified manually).
```

Have anybody any ideas?

ADD:

I tested this regexp at http://www.regextester.com/ -- it behaved as expected too.

ADD:

I built a shared library using boost's regexp sources without any changes in them; I done this with this lines in makefile:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -I../../include -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
```

and

```
g++ -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -o "libregex.so" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

Maybe I need to adjust the Unicode options of the boost::regex?..

Comment: Try `"(?:^|\\R)[ \t]*(-[\\s\\S]*?)(?=\\R[ \t]*-|$)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boost uses the Perl's syntax, so the `$` matches not only the end of line, but a "just before a new line" too (described [here](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2343)). So adding the `regex_constants::no_mod_m` to the regex's flags solved my issue.

Another method is to change the expression as follows:

```
(?:\\A|\\n)[ \\t]*(-.*?)(?=\\n[ \\t]*-|\\z)
```

or even:

```
^[ \\t]*(-.*?)(?=\\n[ \\t]*-|\\z)
```